# How do I make a job mutually exclusive with a set of jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have in Jenkins a set of jobs `A1, A2, ...` that can be executed concurrently, as well as a job `B` that must never be executed concurrently with any job `Ai`. All these jobs run on the same node (the jobs `Ai` use a pool of executors that, for reasons that can't be helped, occasionally have to be shepherded by job `B`). Can I enforce this in Jenkins?

The concept is similar to that of a [shared mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex); the jobs `Ai` require *shared*-level access to the pool, while the job `B` requires *exclusive*-level access.

I'm looking at the [Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin), but it appears from the options that it provides that it only has one level of access. I could make `B` never be concurrent with any `Ai`, but only by making all `Ai` mutually exclusive as well.

Is there a way to achieve shared-mutex-like behavior, either with this plugin or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There's the [Block queued job plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin):

  > *Plugin for blocking/unblocking job in queue by some conditions configured in this job.*
- There's the  [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin):

  > *This plugin keeps the actual job in the queue if at least one name of currently running jobs is matching with one of the given regular expressions.*